# Kong Ingress controller defining multiple HTTPS ports

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kong, kong-ingress

I am setting up a Kong ingress controller, however, the default ingress controller listening ports are 80/443. I need to add an additional HTTPS port (8080). I can change the default HTTPS port using the `servicePort` in the [values file](https://github.com/Kong/charts/blob/main/charts/kong/values.yaml#L278), however this replaces the default HTTPS port 443 with 8080. Is there a way to add an additional HTTPS port? In the API Gateway we used to be able to define it in the [proxy_listen](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/reference/configuration/#proxy_listen) config, however, this doesn't seem to work in the Kong Ingress controller.

Answer (score 0):

You will need customize the chart,

```
  {{- if .tls.enabled }}
  - name: kong-{{ .serviceName }}-tls
    port: {{ .tls.servicePort }}
    targetPort: {{ .tls.overrideServiceTargetPort | default .tls.containerPort }}
    appProtocol: https
  - name: kong-{{ .serviceName }}-tls-customize
    port: {{ .tls.servicePort_custom }}
    targetPort: {{ .tls.overrideServiceTargetPort | default .tls.containerPort }}
    appProtocol: https
```

[_helpers.tpl#L176](https://github.com/Kong/charts/blob/d3ff551d5c1acf5960872eb73a7fe1d1c92e23cd/charts/kong/templates/_helpers.tpl#L176)

and it will produce something like this

```
  - name: kong-proxy-tls
    port: 443
    targetPort: 8443
    appProtocol: https
  - name: kong-proxy-custom-tls
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8443
```

But i see something in the ENV, which seems like some binding so i do not belive it will work

```
        - name: KONG_PORT_MAPS
          value: "80:8000, 443:8443"
```

so seems like multiple change is involve or might be some limitations but this how you can play with chart, download it and customize it.

you can also try `proxy_listen` that was suppose to working with you before.

[proxy_helpers.tpl#L209](https://github.com/Kong/charts/blob/d3ff551d5c1acf5960872eb73a7fe1d1c92e23cd/charts/kong/templates/_https://github.com/Kong/charts/blob/d3ff551d5c1acf5960872eb73a7fe1d1c92e23cd/charts/kong/templates/_helpers.tpl#L209)

```
  {{- if .tls -}}
    {{- if .tls.enabled -}}
      {{/*
      This is a bit of a hack to support always including "ssl" in the parameter
      list for TLS listens. It's not possible to set a variable to an object from
      .Values and then modify one of the objects values locally, although
      https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4987 indicates it should be. Instead,
      this creates a new object and new parameters list built from the original.
      */}}
      {{- $listenConfig := dict -}}
      {{- $listenConfig := merge $listenConfig .tls -}}
      {{- $parameters := append .tls.parameters "ssl" -}}
      {{- $_ := set $listenConfig "parameters" $parameters -}}
      {{- $_ := set $listenConfig "address" (default "0.0.0.0" .address) -}}
      {{- $tlsListen := (include "kong.singleListen" $listenConfig) -}}
      {{- $unifiedListen = append $unifiedListen $tlsListen -}}
    {{- end -}}
  {{- end -}}
```

[listen-values.yaml#L145](https://github.com/Kong/charts/blob/76b402eab66641084d21e8e9bde1e71655ca892e/charts/kong/values.yaml#L145)

[listen_helpers.tpl#L238](https://github.com/Kong/charts/blob/d3ff551d5c1acf5960872eb73a7fe1d1c92e23cd/charts/kong/templates/_helpers.tpl#L238)